# Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.props Not Found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

So, I have been trying to fix this error I am getting over a month now, but with no success. I am currently working on a personal app project in collaboration with one other friend and surprisingly the project compiles perfectly fine on my friend's machine.

I am getting the below error:

**"The imported project "C:\Users\divye\Documents\NHSF Xamarin App\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.280555\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk".**

I can't understand why my code will not compile. I have gone through lots and lots of Stack Overflow posts already and tried pretty much all the proposed solutions without any success. As a last resort I am having to post on here.

I have tried the following:

- Deleted the project locally from my machine and re-cloned the git repository and then tried running the project
- Cleaned the project out and tried rebuilding again
- Have spoken with my friend who is also working on the project, and matched my local project set out to his
- I have gone into the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android .csproject files and also manually added in the Import statement for 'Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.props'
- I have manually checked the folder '$..\netstandard1.0\ folder path to make sure the 'Xamarin.Forms.DefaultItems.props' file physically exists in the folder and it does for both iOS and Android.
- Updated all packages in Xamarin Studio for the project to make sure latest versions of the packages are being used
- Downgraded the Xamarin.Forms package to see if it could be to do with a bug in the latest package but this does not seem to be the issue.
- A suggested fix that worked for my friend was recreating the project to contain the ASP.NET backend for mobile packages. I have tried this as well.
- I was initially getting the error on my Mac so I thought I would give it a go on my Windows machine. Same thing happens on there too.

I am stumped at the issue. It is failing to build at all. Neither iOS or Android work.

I am hoping someone from here can help.

Thanks,

Divyesh!

Comment: 1) Do not post images/pictures of errors, post the formatted error text directly in your question. 2) Make sure that in your git repo you have not checked in the `package` directory (and anything within it).

Comment: In addition, I would avoid pathnames with whitespaces

Comment: @SushiHangover I checked my repo and the package directory was not committed, so that wasn't the issue. Thanks for your help and apologies it has taken a while to get back to you.

Comment: @hichame.yessou Indeed whitespaces in my pathname was the reason behind the issue. I renamed the project in git and removed and spaces and re cloned and the project both compiled and ran just fine. Thank you! This I will keep in mind for future.

Comment: @dbchudasama Nice, I'll post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the whitespaces in the pathname of the project!